# Method for decoupling objects dependent on another object

Tags: design-patterns

I am writing an app to record drum tablature (specifically for a [sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlGw7.jpg)).  I am following the conventions of the sampler which are:

1. A **Sequence** is 1 or more **Tracks**.  A **Sequence** can be [quantized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization) (break the measure up into equal parts).
2. A **Track** is an instrument or sound that will be played at certain parts of a measure.  Each **Track** is broken up into parts.  The number of parts is determined by the quantization of the **Sequence**.  As an example, if the quantization is set to 1/16, the array will have length of 16.  Each element of the array then stores whether or not the sound should play at that step in the **Sequence**.

Naturally, I have one object to represent a **Sequence**.  It has an attribute called `tracks` which is an array of **Track** objects.  A **Track** object has an array attribute that is in equal length to the quantization of the **Sequence**.

I am suffering major analysis paralysis and am unable to determine **What is a clean way for all `Track` objects belonging to a specific `Sequence` to know when the quantization has changed so it can update its own internal array?**

Or

**How should the `Track` object know what to set its array length to without coupling the `Sequence` object?**

Comment: Can tracks exist independently of a sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every track must belong to one and only one sequence, then they are coupled by nature. Reflecting that coupling in implementation is not a problem (except perhaps for unit tests).

Since the sequence initiates this change, I would recommend a publicly-accessible method on the `Sequence` object that sets the quantization for the sequence as a whole, and then iterates through the sequence's tracks to set their quantization. `Sequence.setQuantization()` would be publicly accessible, `Track.setQuantization()` should not be.

To ensure that the coupling is maintained, I'd also limit the ability to create `Track` objects to a factory method on `Sequence` (eg: `addTrack()`).

That opens up the question of independently unit testing `Track` and `Sequence`. One way to do this is to create these objects as interfaces, and then have a single implementation of each with hooks for testing code. That leads to its own ugliness, probably including a `SequenceFactory`, but only you can decide how much purity you need.